# Animate css on page load

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to action a css animation when the page loads? I'm exploring with css animations right now as I have never really worked with them.

So far I have created this: https://jsfiddle.net/7prg793g however it only works currently by hover over.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.reveal {
  width: 380px;
  height: 660px;
  margin: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.open {
  background: url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px 330px, url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px -405px, #42413C;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
}

.open:hover {
  background: url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px 660px, url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px -735px, #42413C;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.reveal p {
  font: 45px/300px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.reveal:hover p {
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

If this is possible, then my next question would be is it possible to delay the animation until the div is actually visible? I'm going to be using a preloader before hand.

Thank you.

Comment: you will neet to use javascript or any javascript framework like jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pure CSS solution (keyframes)

This solution is okay but it depends the compatibility that you want with browsers:

```
@keyframes opening {
    0% {
          background: url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px 330px, url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px -405px, #42413C;
    }
    100% {
       background: url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px 660px, url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px -735px, #42413C;
    }
}

@keyframes opening-p {
    0% {
      -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;    
    }
    100% {
      -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I created two keyframes to use as animation with the div and text. After I attached the animation in this way (using animation-fill-mode:forwards;)

```
.open {
    background: url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px 330px, url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px -405px, #42413C;
  background:no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  animation-name: opening;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.reveal p {
  font: 45px/300px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  animation-name: opening-p;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8anvmpfv/

### jQuery solution

So it's easy to do with jquery:

```
  $('.reveal').ready(function() {
      $('.reveal').addClass('opened revealed');
  });
```

It waits the div to be ready and jquery give to the div the right class that does the animation with css.
Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6faf0fu/

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript to add css animation on pageload:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("yourHtmlTag").addClass("open:hover");
});
```

For on visibility, look into [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: `.open` is for the static position - `.open:hover` contains the background transition

Comment: AddClass('open') without the dot.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with pure css I believe (by setting animation delays and doing some math to figure everything out), but I think your best bet would be with some javascript as well.

[Here's a fiddle of a very basic (and ugly) loading animation screen.](http://jsfiddle.net/rka29s18/)

You start the page with the `body` 'locked' and some sort of overlay to prevent users from interacting with the site. Then you listen for the `transitionend` of the various elements to know when to fire additional `transitions`.

You could do the same thing with css animations, just use `animationend` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it the last thing on the page. That would cause it to happen only once the rest of the assets loaded. Not including images.